# python combine two arrays by the key column

Tags: arrays, python-2.7

I have two arrays like:

```
a = [['a', '11', '111'],['b','22','222'],['a','33','333'],['b','44','444']]
b = [['a','0.1','1'],['b','0.9','0']]
```

I want to combine a and b based on the first column and get the result like:

```
[['a', '11', '111', '0.1', '1'], ['b', '22', '222', '0.9', '0'], ['a','33','333', '0.1', '1'], ['b','44','444', '0.9', '0']]
```

I made array `b` as a dictionary and loop each line in `a`, and extend the line by the value got from the dictionary `b`. Does anyone have an elegant way to do this?

Comment: Your bottom solution is how I'd do it.  Are you having problems with the implementation or are you just asking if there's a better way algorithmically (there's not)?

Answer (score 0):

Using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) you could obtain the result using `pandas.merge`:

```
In [72]: a = [['a', '11', '111'],['b','22','222'],['a','33','333'],['b','44','444']]

In [73]: b = [['a','0.1','1'],['b','0.9','0']]

In [74]: import pandas as pd

In [75]: a = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=('key', 'col1', 'col2'))

In [76]: b = pd.DataFrame(b, columns=('key', 'col3', 'col4'))

In [77]: df = pd.merge(a, b, on=['key']); df
Out[77]: 
  key col1 col2 col3 col4
0   a   11  111  0.1    1
1   a   33  333  0.1    1
2   b   22  222  0.9    0
3   b   44  444  0.9    0

In [81]: df.values.tolist()
Out[84]: 
[['a', '11', '111', '0.1', '1'],
 ['a', '33', '333', '0.1', '1'],
 ['b', '22', '222', '0.9', '0'],
 ['b', '44', '444', '0.9', '0']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your proposed method is just elegant enough:

```
>>> a = [['a', '11', '111'],['b','22','222'],['a','33','333'],['b','44','444']]
>>> b = [['a','0.1','1'],['b','0.9','0']]
>>> b_ex = dict([(l[0], l[1:]) for l in b])
>>> [x+b_ex[x[0]] for x in a]
[['a', '11', '111', '0.1', '1'], ['b', '22', '222', '0.9', '0'], ['a', '33', '333', '0.1', '1'], ['b', '44', '444', '0.9', '0']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple, using nested list comprehensions:

```
>>> [a1 + [b1[1:] for b1 in b if b1[0] == a1[0]][0] for a1 in a]
[['a', '11', '111', '0.1', '1'], 
 ['b', '22', '222', '0.9', '0'], 
 ['a', '33', '333', '0.1', '1'], 
 ['b', '44', '444', '0.9', '0']]
```

Answer (score 0):

How does it look like: `[(x+b[x[0]]) for x in a]`?

Details:

```
>>> a = [['a', '11', '111'], ['b', '22', '222'], ['a', '33', '333'], ['b', '44', '444']]
>>> b = {'a': ['0.1', '1'], 'b': ['0.9', '0']}
>>> [(x+b[x[0]]) for x in a]
[['a', '11', '111', '0.1', '1'], ['b', '22', '222', '0.9', '0'], ['a', '33', '333', '0.1', '1'], ['b', '44', '444', '0.9', '0']]
>>>
```

Comment: `b` is a list - **not** a dict.

Comment: He said he made b a dict. "I made array b as a dictionary"

Comment: And then he asked for a more elegant solution. Not for anyone to repeat half of his.